# install MySQL Server 5.0 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, centos6

How can I install MySQL version 5.0.x to CentOS 6.3. The MySQL in CentOS 6.3 is version 5.1. The MySQL 5.0.x is required to run a slave database of a master database server running MySQL 5.0.x

Comment: Why not to use 5.1.x as a slave of 5.0? It's perfectly OK. I used to use 5.5.x as a slave of 5.0.x without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download 5.0.96 packages [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#downloads), just select 5.0.96 at the "Select Version" dropdown box.